# How to define pos_pattern for extracting nouns followed by zero or more sequence of nouns or adjectives for KeyphraseCountVectorizer?

Tags: nlp, part-of-speech, keyword-extraction

I'm trying to extract Arabic keywords from tweets. I'm using keyBERT with KeyphraseCountVectorizer

`vectorizer = KeyphraseCountVectorizer(pos_pattern='< N.*>*')`

I'm trying to write more custom pos patterns regExp to select nouns followed by zero or more sequence of nouns or adjectives but not verbs.
can you please help me to write the right regExp?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your requirement to match "nouns followed by zero or more sequence of nouns or adjectives" as matching at least one or more sequential nouns (i.e. `<N.*>+`), followed by zero or more adjectives (i.e. `<J.*>*`). So putting these together you get the full RegExp as follows:

```py
vectorizer = KeyphraseCountVectorizer(pos_pattern="<N.*>+<J.*>*")
```

As a side point, you note that you are attempting to extract *Arabic* keywords. From my understanding the [keyphrase_vectorizers](https://pypi.org/project/keyphrase-vectorizers/) package relies on the text being annotated with `spaCy` PoS tags, and so to change languages from the default (English) you have to load a corresponding [pipeline/model](https://spacy.io/models) in the desired language and set the stop words to those of the new language. For example, if using the Keyphrase Vectorizer for German:

```py
vectorizer = KeyphraseCountVectorizer(spacy_pipeline='de_core_news_sm', stop_words='german')
```

However, at present `spaCy` does not have a pipeline trained for Arabic text, which means that using `KeyphraseCountVectorizer` in a straightforward manner with Arabic text is not possible without workarounds (something you may have already solved but I just thought I'd mention it).